# Apache Alias and LocationMatch togheter

Tags: apache-2.4

I am trying to configure Apache to serve 3 application with this url schema.

For **http://10.1.0.101** and **http://10.1.0.101/App1** requests are forwarded to another server. For a special url for App1 an output filter is called (it works).

For http://10.1.0.101/App2 requests are forwarded to Tomcat (it works)

For http://10.1.0.101/App3 requests should be forwarded to /var/www/html but it doesn't works and I got a 404. How can I use the directvive Alias to works as expected?

Thanks to all

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName 10.1.0.101
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On

   #Define a filter
ExtFilterDefine outFilter mode=output \
cmd="/var/www/cgi-bin/out-filter.pl /tmp/out-filter.out"

   DocumentRoot /var/wwww/html

   #forward app3 to /var/www/html ->*** It doensn't work *** 
   Alias /app3 /var/www/html

   #Make App1 default app when user use http://10.1.0.101 ->It works
   <LocationMatch "">
      ProxyPassMatch  http://10.1.0.100/App1
      ProxyPassReverse  http://10.1.0.100/App1
   </LocationMatch>

   #Forward to App2. ->It works
   <LocationMatch "^/app2(.*)">
      ProxyPassMatch   http://localhost:8080/app2$1
      ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/app2/$1
   </LocationMatch>

   #Forward to App1 -> It works
   <LocationMatch "^/app1(.*)">
      ProxyPassMatch   http://10.1.0.100/App1$1
      ProxyPassReverse http://10.1.0.100/App1$1
   </LocationMatch>

   #Forward to App1 and call the filter -> It works
   <LocationMatch "^/App1/specialpage(.*)">
      ProxyPassMatch   http://10.1.0.100/App1/specialpage$1
      ProxyPassReverse http://10.1.0.100/App1/specialpage$1

      SetOutputFilter   outFilter
   </LocationMatch>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Using "curl -I" command, I noted that /app3 are forwarded wrongly to http://10.1.0.100 so LocationMatch take priority to Alias directive. How I can invert the order?

Answer (score 0):

Put your [`Alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive in a Location(Match) as well to ensure that URL path is [merged consistently](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging) with your other sections.

```
   <LocationMatch "^/app3(.*)">
        Alias "/var/www/html"
   </LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks @HBruijn♦ but I got and error starting Apache:  "Alias not allowed here"

Comment: Hmmm, that syntax is dependant on he Apache http version *"This syntax is available in Apache 2.4.19 and later."*

Comment: I will try to update Apache